# To what extent should a question such as: "how many enantiomers are there?" take geometric isomerism into account?

Tags: stereochemistry, isomers, chirality, cis-trans-isomerism

Pretty simple question here.

> How many enantiomers are there for the structure $\ce{CH3CH=CHCH(CH3)CH2CH3}$?

On the one hand, there is just one chiral centre so one would suggest $2$. On the other hand, there is some E/Z cis/trans isomerism at play leading to four distinct *stereo*isomers.

I made a sketch:

[image: Displayed formulae of stereoisomers]

If I'm not mistaken, $(A)-(D)$ are distinct molecules. Let's say we favour $(A)$. Would we say that the only enantiomer of $(A)$ is $(B)$, or would we say that all of $(B),(C),(D)$ are enantiomers of $(A)$?

I ask because I have been hearing some confused messages from my chemistry teacher and for a question as specific as this, I could not find a satisfactory online discussion. I would personally count them all as different enantiomers since it is truly a different arrangement of atoms in space and it is reasonable to suppose that all of them have slightly different optical properties.

What would you say?

Comment: I think there is a H missing in the formula. / On the matter at hand, I'd say there are two sets of enantiomers (a and b, c and d). Everything else would be ambiguous at best. Enantiomers always come in pairs, so the answer is pretty much always two and only differs in the number of sets.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン There is a missing $H$ yes. Thank you for sharing your thoughts

Comment: Please [edit] the question to fix the error.

Comment: A chiral atom has four different groups attached. Enantiomers refer to a comparison between two stereoisomers. So enantiomers are steroisomers that are non-superimposable mirror images (=chirality). While enantiomers contain chiral centers in the molecules, but not all stereoisomers of a molecule are enantiomers of each other. *It's such an uncomfortably boggling jargon* - always drawing them helps !

Comment: @bonCodigo So you seem to be suggesting only $(A),(B)$ and $(C),(D)$ are enantiomers.

Comment: FShrike That's correct but @Martin-マーチン would be a better explainer for you.